# queryString to java parameter

Tags: java, string, url, parameters

So what I am trying to do was getting the url queryString to a value in java as a string, I looked up couples of solution and try it out nothing works for me.

One of the solution I tried: 
[Parse a query string parameter to java object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281701/parse-a-query-string-parameter-to-java-object)

In the URL I got something like this:

http://www.somethingCool.com?AreYouCool=Y

How do I get AreYouCool as a java String

Comment: Can you please add some code that you have tried so far?

Comment: String YouCool=(String) request.getParameter("AreYouCool");  in java

Answer (score 0):

Use Pattern and Matcher classes to get the key part.

```
Pattern.compile("(?<=\\?).*?(?==)");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wE7nB6/1)

Answer (score 0):

String YouCool=(String) request.getParameter("AreYouCool")

works